# loop for making program start from the beginning

Tags: c++

i have to make the Programm start from the beginning if it goes to the default value in the switch

i don't know what to try

```
switch(eingabe)
{
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
        cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
        cin >> gzahl1;
        cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
        cin >> gzahl2;
        cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
        break;
    case 'f':
    case 'F':
        cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
        cin >> fzahl1;
        cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
        cin >> fzahl2;
        cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
        break;
    default: cout << "ungueltige eingabe";
}
```

i need the programm to start again from the beginning if it happens to get to the default value in the switch.

Comment: Try wrapping the block in a `while(someBoolVariable) { ... }` loop and set `someBoolVariable` appropriately inside the `switch/case` branches.

Comment: By beginning, do you mean `switch` statement start?

Comment: yes sorry for not clarifing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lubgr's comment stated, you can wrap the whole block in a `while` loop. So for your cases, this might work:

```
//start of program {
bool correct_input = false;
while(!correct_input)
{
    //code before the switch
    switch(eingabe)
    {
        case 'g':
        case 'G':
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
            //set correct_input to true 
            correct_input = true;
        break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
            //set correct_input to true
            correct_input = true;
        break;
        default: 
            cout << "ungueltige eingabe";
            //next line is optional
            correct_input = false;
        break;
    }
}
//continue if correct input is inserted
//end of program }
```

And yes, you can use [`goto`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_goto_statement.htm) in the `default switch` to make your life "easier", but it is strongly discourage as stated also in the link, because it will result in [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). So yea, use`while`, or maybe `do while` also.

Answer (score 1):

try the following approach:

```
bool continueCase = true;
while (continueCase)
{
    switch (eingabe)
    {
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
        cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
        cin >> gzahl1;
        cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
        cin >> gzahl2;
        cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
        continueCase = false;
        break;
    case 'f':
    case 'F':
        cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
        cin >> fzahl1;
        cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
        cin >> fzahl2;
        cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
        continueCase = false;
        break;
    default: cout << "ungueltige eingabe";
        continueCase = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach #1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char eingabe;
    bool isExecuted = false;
    cout << "Bitte geben sie g, G, f oder F ein!\n";
    do {
        cin >> eingabe;
        switch (eingabe)
        {
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
                int gzahl1;
                int gzahl2;
                cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
                cin >> gzahl1;
                cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
                cin >> gzahl2;
                cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
                cout << "Bitte g, f, G oder F eingeben!\nZum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
                isExecuted = true;
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                float fzahl1;
                float fzahl2;
                cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
                cin >> fzahl1;
                cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
                cin >> fzahl2;
                cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
                cout << "Bitte g, f, G oder F eingeben!\nZum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
                isExecuted = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "ungueltige eingabe\nBitte g, f, G  oder F eingeben! Zum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
                isExecuted = false;
                break;
        }
    } while ( false == isExecuted);
    return 0;
}
```

Approach #2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char eingabe;
    bool isExecuted = false;
    do
    {
        cin >> eingabe;
        isExecuted = processEvent(eingabe);
    }while(isExecuted == false);  
    return 0;
}

bool processEvent(char eingabe)
{
    bool execStatus = false;
    cout << "Bitte geben sie g, G, f oder F ein!\n";
    switch (eingabe)
    {
        case 'g':
        case 'G':
            int gzahl1;
            int gzahl2;
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
            cout << "Bitte g, f, G oder F eingeben!\nZum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
            execStatus = true;
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            float fzahl1;
            float fzahl2;
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
            cout << "Bitte g, f, G oder F eingeben!\nZum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
            execStatus = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ungueltige eingabe\nBitte g, f, G  oder F eingeben! Zum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
            break;
    }
return execStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use goto statement like this

```
loop:
    switch(eingabe)
    {
        case 'g':
        case 'G':
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
            break;
        default: 
            cout << "ungueltige eingabe";
            goto loop;
    }
```

or you can use for loop like this

```
for( ;;)
{
    switch(eingabe)
    {
        case 'g':
        case 'G':
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> gzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl1;
            cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
            cin >> fzahl2;
            cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
            break;
        default: 
            cout << "ungueltige eingabe";
            continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a do-while Loop (see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) to keep asking for user input. When the user enters x, the program terminates. When the user enters g, G, f or F, the switch cases for those letters are executed. When the user enters something else the default case is executed. The important lines for repetitive asking are the following.

```
do {
```

and

```
} while (eingabe != 'x');
```

They make up the do-while Loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char eingabe;
    cout << "Bitte geben sie g, G, f oder F ein!\n";
    do {
        cin >> eingabe;
        switch (eingabe){
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
                int gzahl1;
                int gzahl2;
                cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein BITTE GANZZAHLEN" << endl;
                cin >> gzahl1;
                cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
                cin >> gzahl2;
                cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << gzahl1 / gzahl2 << endl;
                cout << "Bitte g, f, G oder F eingeben!\nZum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                float fzahl1;
                float fzahl2;
                cout << "Geben sie bitte die erste zahl ein" << endl;
                cin >> fzahl1;
                cout << "geben sie bitte die zweite zahl ein" << endl;
                cin >> fzahl2;
                cout << "das ergebnis lautet: " << fzahl1 / fzahl2 << endl;
                cout << "Bitte g, f, G oder F eingeben!\nZum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "ungueltige eingabe\nBitte g, f, G  oder F eingeben! Zum Beenden des Programms x eingeben.\n";
                break;
        }
    } while (eingabe != 'x');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When user gives g,  it will be infinite loop. But the user wants only one execution